# Contact form in Ruby on Rails mailer not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, heroku, mailgun

I'm making simple contact form without any fancy gems and I think I'm finished, except nothing works in production.

I'm using `rails 4.2.0` in `Cloud9` IDE. For production I'm using `Heroku` and for mailer `Mailgun` service witch is enabled in Heroku.

When i try to send mail in development environment i see email being sent in server console, but when I try to do it in production, it doesn't send email and it doesn't redirect me back to contact form page(as it do in development environment). Maybe I'm just not using Mailgun correctly, if so, can you give some good `gmail` tutorial for mailer, so I can make it work on Heroku and Digital Ocean hosting platform.

messages_controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController 

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)

    if @message.valid?
      MessageMailer.message_me(@message).deliver_now
      redirect_to new_message_path, notice: "Thankyou for your message."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:name, :email, :subject, :content)
    end
end
```

message_mailer.rb

```
class MessageMailer < ApplicationMailer
  # use your own email address here
  default :to => "MYMAIL@gmail.com"

  def message_me(msg)
  @msg = msg

    mail(from: @msg.email, subject: @msg.subject, body: @msg.content)
  end
end
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :port           => ENV['587'],
    :address        => ENV['smtp.mailgun.org'],
    :user_name      => ENV['SANDBOX USERNAME GIVEN BY MAILGUN'],
    :password       => ENV['PASWORD'],
    :domain         => 'MYAPP.herokuapp.com', #eg: 'yourappname.herokuapp.com'
    :authentication => :plain,
  }
```

models/message.rb

```
class Message
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name, :email, :subject, :content

  validates :name, :email, :subject, :content, presence: true
end
```

views/messages/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @message do |f| %>
  <% if @message.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= "#{pluralize(@message.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this message from being sent:" %></h2>
      <ul>
        <% @message.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      <ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :subject %>
    <%= f.text_field :subject %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Send', class: 'button' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SMTP configuration looks wrong. It should be loading the config values from environment variables, but you appear to be trying to place the values in there:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :port           => ENV['587'],
  :address        => ENV['smtp.mailgun.org']
  :user_name      => ENV['SANDBOX USERNAME GIVEN BY MAILGUN'],
  :password       => ENV['PASWORD'],
  :domain         => 'MYAPP.herokuapp.com', #eg: 'yourappname.herokuapp.com'
  :authentication => :plain,
}
```

This should actually be setup like:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :port           => 587,
  :address        => 'smtp.mailgun.org'
  :user_name      => ENV['MAILGUN_USERNAME'],
  :password       => ENV['MAILGUN_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'MYAPP.herokuapp.com', #eg: 'yourappname.herokuapp.com'
  :authentication => :plain,
}
```

Then you will need to set those MAILGUN_USERNAME and MAILGUN_PASSWORD environment variables in your Cloud 9 Run panel.

Comment: how can i set those variables in Cloud 9 and Heroku?

Comment: There is an ENV button on the Cloud 9 panel where you can set them.  For Heroku use `heroku config:set MAILGUN_USERNAME=myvalue`

Comment: OMG. finally everything works perfectly. if i could give upvote I would do it :D because of my reputatation. I will mark as answered. Thanks so much.